# Iterate over a fixed number of files with Bash/Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a list of 2000 files in a folder. I need to iterate over 10 files, execute a shell command for each file (total 10 commands), wait for the batch to complete and iterate over the next 10 files until no files left.

Ideally, i would like to delete the files in /path/to/source_dir/ that i have already done iterating over. I'm not able to figure this out. Any advise would be helpful.

```
find /path/to/source_dir -type f -print0 | sed 's/\/path\/to\/source_dir\///g' |xargs -0 -L10 sh -c '{ for i in $@; do /opt/dns_parse/1.1/bin/dns_parse -F avro -dc -e $SOURCE -i $SENSOR -B /path/to/dest_dir/$i /path/to/source_dir/"$i" & done; wait}'
```

Comment: Try to remove `{` and `}` in your command, it works on my computer.

Comment: @VictorLee no, you are failing to process the first of each ten arguments. `seq 1 100 | xargs -L10 sh -c 'for i in "$@"; do echo -n "[$i]" & done; wait; echo'`. You also need an extra trailing dummy argument to `sh`

Comment: @jhnc yes, `$@`  refers to all of arguments: `$1` , `$2` , etc. In this case it will ignore the `$0`, so this command line works: `seq 1 100 | xargs -n10 sh -c 'echo -n [$0] & for i in "$@"; do echo -n "[$i]" & done; wait; echo'`

Comment: @VictorLee the [normal way](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Invoking-the-shell-from-xargs.html) is `... | xargs ... sh -c 'command' _` (or some other dummy argument)

Comment: @jhnc THX, cool, but why `_` could replace `move` in this command ?

Comment: @VictorLee because we don't care about the value in this case (as long as it doesn't start with `-`). Look up `sh` manpage for syntax of `-c` option and processing of `$0` that starts with `-` (!= `_`)

Comment: @jhnc I see, THX, @user2051904, in your case, you could use other delimiter such as `|` instead of `/`, so you don't need to escape the `/` in replace pattern string.

Answer (score 2):

You can instruct Bash to read only 10 entries at a time with `mapfile -n 10`.

Here is a featured script using `mapfile`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source_dir='/path/to/source_dir/'

find "$source_dir" -type f -print0 |
  # Map a list of maximum ten files
  while mapfile -d '' -n 10 files_per_ten && [ ${#files_per_ten[@]} -gt 0 ]; do
    # Iterate indexes in the list
    for source_file_path in "${files_per_ten[@]}"; do
      # Strip the leading source_dir path out of the source_file_path
      source_file="${source_file_path#$source_dir}"
      # If executing the dns_parse command is successful
      if /opt/dns_parse/1.1/bin/dns_parse \
        -F avro -dc -e "$SOURCE" -i "$SENSOR" \
        -B "/path/to/dest_dir/$source_file" "$source_file_path"
      then
        # Delete the source file
        rm -f -- "$source_file_path"
      fi & # Run the if-fi commands group as a background task
    done
    # Wait all background tasks
    wait
  done
```

Comment: @oguzismail Thank you! I overlooked this. I now moved the deletion within the background task because it is less computation than handling an asynchronous delete list.

Comment: what does `-d ''` do? Looks like my linux distribution (CentOS 7) doesn't recognize it. I removed that switch and tried the script, its working but it's not processing dns_parse for the 10 files that "mapfile" collects. It's waiting on the first one to complete and moves on to next.

Comment: I tested if files_per_ten contains the 10 file name but after running the command, array returns 0 elements. `find /var/storage/testing/ -type f -print0 | mapfile -n 10 files_per_ten`

Comment: @user2051904 it contains 0 element because you did not set a null delimiter to mapfile with `mapfile -d ''`

Answer (score 0):

So read 10 lines at a time.

```
find ..... -print0 |
while
     files=()
     for ((i=0; i<10; ++i)); do
         if ! IFS= read -r -d '' tmp; then
               break
         fi
         files+=("$tmp")
     done
     (( ${#files[@]} ))
do
     # use "${files[@]}"
done
```

but tbh just wait each 10 files.

```
find .... | {
    num=0
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; then
          stuff "$file" &
          if ((num++ == 10)); then
               wait
               num=0
          fi
    done
 }
```

If you intent to use `xargs` and have bash, do not do `xargs sh -c 'very long unreadable double-qouted stuff here'`. Export a bash function.

```
mywork() {
   stuff here
   readable
}
export -f mywork
find .... | xargs bash -c 'mywork "$@"' _
```

The `wait}'` will be a syntax error - there has to be a `;` before `}`, like `wait; }'`. `for i in $@` will undergo word splitting. Remember to check your scripts with shellcheck . `-0 -L10` is odd, I would do `-0 -n10`.

Answer (score 0):

Process 10 files at a time and wait until the batch is done.
In the script below 30 `sleep` scripts are created for demonstration purposes.

```
#!/bin/bash

source="$HOME/tmp/mp3"

# create 30 dummy sleep scripts
for i in {1..30}; do echo "sleep 5" > "file$i"; chmod 755 "file$i"; done
echo "$(find "${source}" -name 'file*' | wc -l) files to process"
i=0
c=0
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    while [ "$i" -eq 10 ] && jobs -l | tr '\n' ';' | grep -q 'Running' ; do
      echo "waiting $(jobs -l | grep -c 'Running') processes"
      # tune this value as needed
      sleep 6
    done

    if [ "$i" -eq 10 ]; then
        echo "10 files processed"
        i=0
    fi
    if [ "$i" -lt 10 ]; then
        echo "Processing $i"
        ##### process to wait for ####
        source "$(basename "$file")" &
        ((i=i+1))
    fi
    ((c=c+1))
done < <(find  "${source}" -type f -print0)

echo "Total $c files processed"

rm "${source}"/file*
```

**Output:**

```
30 files to process
Processing 0
Processing 1
Processing 2
...
Processing 9
waiting 10 processes
10 files processed
Processing 0
Processing 1
...
Processing 9
waiting 10 processes
10 files processed
Processing 0
Processing 1
Processing 2
...
Processing 9
Total 30 files processed
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the improvements made there.